# Where does the expression 'te conozco, bacalao' come from?

Tags: etimología

The expression '**te conozco, bacalao**' appears in the  [Diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4jHz5SC) as:

> 1. expr. coloq. Usada para indicar que se conocen las intenciones o el modo de actuar de alguien.

Does anybody know the origin, and why 'bacalao' was chosen instead of any other word?

Comment: De momento he encontrado [una ficha](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_B/LETRA_B_PDF/BACALAO/00000235.pdf) (PDF) en el fichero general de la RAE que menciona la expresión, y es de 1980.

Comment: El [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) indica que se recoge solamente desde 2001. En 1992 no aparecía aún.

Comment: There is a 70s song _Te conozco_ by Héctor Lavoe that uses this expression. I could not find references in Ngram, though.

Answer (score 3):

La aparición más antigua que he encontrado de la expresión ha sido en la hemeroteca del diario ABC (un recurso bastante interesante para este tipo de menesteres, ya que tienen escaneados todos los ejemplares desde sus inicios). Concretamente en la edición de la mañana del [17 de junio de 1923](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1923/06/17/018.html).

> La Policía descubrió un comercio ilícito de bacalao que se vendía en los barrios altos a peseta el kilo, razonable precio antaño, inverosímil hogaño, por haber pasado a ser plato de príncipes y magnates. Por cierto que la mercancía procedía de Cáceres, que no es precisamente Escocia, con lo que resulta que la Policía podrá decir en lo sucesivo: Te conozco, bacalao, aunque vengas extremeño.

La siguiente aparición es en la edición del [2 de diciembre de 1960](http://hemeroteca.abc.es/nav/Navigate.exe/hemeroteca/madrid/abc/1960/12/02/031.html), un artículo que precisamente se llama "¡Te conozco, bacalao!". En este artículo se explica:

> Tal dice el dicho, porque el bacalao es manjar de fuerte sabor que necesita de aderezos y disfraces para hacerse apetitoso.

Es decir, el dicho hay que entenderlo en principio de forma literal para conocer su origen, dadas las características del bacalao y dado que seguramente muchos sitios intentarían vender bacalao como un pez de más calidad a base de aderezos. Sería una expresión de origen similar, pues, a la de *dar gato por liebre*. Si te fijas, en el artículo de 1923 se habla de que el bacalao pasó a ser un plato de ricos cuando antes lo era de pobres dado su fuerte sabor (de ahí el aumento de precio del que hablan). El origen del dicho habrá que buscarlo seguramente en el siglo XIX, o principios del XX como muy tarde.

Ahora bien, en algún momento (ignoro cuándo) el dicho pasaría a tener un sentido más figurado, resultando fácil la conexión entre "un pez malo adornado como uno bueno" a "una persona mala adornada como buena". A fin de cuentas, según el diccionario, hasta finales del siglo XIX la palabra "bacalao" designaba también a una "persona flaca y seca de carnes" (DRAE, edición de 1884, en la edición de 1899 esta acepción ya ha desaparecido).